# Gboard not switching back to previous language

Tags: keyboard

I have three languages (Hebrew, Russian, and English) that I use regularly. I also have two others (Arabic and Esperanto) that I use occasionally and have installed.

Usually, whenever I hit the language button, it switches back to my most recent language (which is very convenient for typing in two languages- one tap to switch to Hebrew and one tap to switch back to English).

However, since yesterday, I've had to cycle through all my installed languages to get to the one I need. I tried restarting my phone, but it didn't help. Is there some setting I'm missing or something an app could have done to change why this is occurring?

Comment: Seems to have been an update :( I can't find any option to undo it

Comment: Indeed. The last update was the Friday before it started happening and I barely used my phone all weekend. I hope it's fixed (I just added Greek to the languages I need to occasionally type).

Comment: Experiencing it too since sometime last week, extremely annoying. For now I'm removing the less frequent languages. By the way removing the languages and re-enabling them doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently fixed as of the most recent update (6.7.15.175732024) on November 15th.

Comment: Yes!!! Finally!